# Rails 3: form_for missing closing </form> tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I am using a form_for in one of my views in my rails app, but for some reason the closing tag  is not being generated, and this will be handled safely in most browsers, except IE 8 and lower.

Here's some sample code:

```
<%= form_for object, :remote => true, :url => remote_update_path, :html => {:name => "form_#{id_number}", :id => "form_#{id_number}"} do |f| %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag "field_a", object[:field_a] %>
    <ul class="class1">
        <li> <%= f.check_box :field_b, :class => "class2", :id => "b"  %> B</li>
        <li> <%= f.check_box :field_c, :class => "class2", :id => "c" %> C</li>
    </ul>
 <% end %>
```

For some reason this isn't generating the closing `</form>` tag where `<% end %>` is located. (I know there is now submit button in the form, this does not affect the missing `</form>`.)

Is this a bug? or is there something that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I call lies. Sorry, I know that sounds harsh. The `form_for` helper would not leave out the end for the form tag if it's putting in the beginning. Please show us the complete output for the page.

Comment: The code I gave is pseudocode, so I can't really give you the exact output for the page, but I am sure that the </form> tag is not present. Certain browsers (Chrome, Safari) will fill it in for me, but in IE 6,7,8 that is not the case. My entire form is in a <td> and there is no </form> within that <td> element

Comment: It's impossible for us to debug your issue without seeing real code. If you need us to debug your problem, we're going to need to see the most code you can provide us that will reproduce the issue on your system.

Answer (score 1):

This is almost certainly happening as a result of invalid HTML somewhere on the page. Run it through the [validator](http://validator.w3.org/), until it's all passing, and I bet the problem goes away...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. It happened to me because I didn't close one div tag properly inside the forms.